# Laptop inbuilt keyboard stopped working after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

After updating to Ubuntu 18.04 native laptop keyboard stopped working

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04ca:7063 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d11 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d13 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fb (rev 10)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] (rev 81)
```

`xinput` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput` after switch to `xorg`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera                              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Add more information. Laptop model, output of: 
`lsusb`;
`lspci`;
`xinput`;
`dmesg`;

Comment: @velix please take a look to the outputs

Comment: What version of Ubuntu were you previously using? Did you use xorg instead of wayland? I suggest switching to xorg which is generally more compatible with keyboards and mouse.
Edit  `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncomment the line
`#WaylandEnable=false` by removing the # in front. Then reboot.

Comment: @velix switch to `xorg` did not help but output of `xinput` has changed, i have updated post. I used Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try testing the `Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard` with `xinput test 9` and `xinput test 10` (Id may change after reboot).

Comment: testing does not help

Comment: What does it means? Be more specific.